# Spring Boot 1.3 new @EnableOauth2Sso config and @EnableZuulProxy

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

With the release of Spring Boot 1.3 I'm unable to get OAuth2 token relay working with the new `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation.

With a simple demo:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the following POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the following error on startup:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.proxy.OAuth2ProxyAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.proxy.OAuth2ProxyAutoConfiguration.resourceServerProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.proxy.OAuth2ProxyAutoConfiguration.resourceServerProperties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
```

I'd also like to note that if I try and use the `org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.sso.EnableOAuth2Sso` annotation in a Spring Boot 1.3 project it fails to start with the same error.

What's the correct way to configure OAuth2 SSO and token relay with Spring Boot 1.3?

**Workaround I have for Spring Boot 1.3.0 and Spring Cloud Angel.SR3**

First step is to adjust the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation to exclude the `OAuth2ProxyAutoConfiguration` class like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {OAuth2ProxyAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Then create a custom `@Configuration` class that is essentially mimicking the original `OAuth2ProxyAutoConfiguration` class but removing unneeded pieces.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.TraceRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ProxyRequestHelper;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.proxy.AuthenticationHeaderFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.proxy.OAuth2TokenRelayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.proxy.ProxyAuthenticationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ProxyAuthenticationProperties.class)
public class CustomOAuth2ProxyAutoconfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private ProxyAuthenticationProperties properties;

    // Inject the @Primary one because it knows how to refresh an expired token
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenRelayFilter oauth2TokenRelayFilter() {
        OAuth2TokenRelayFilter filter = new OAuth2TokenRelayFilter(properties);
        filter.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
        return filter;
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationHeaderFilterConfiguration {
        @Autowired(required = false)
        private TraceRepository traces;

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationHeaderFilter authenticationHeaderFilter(
                ProxyAuthenticationProperties properties) {
            ProxyRequestHelper helper = new ProxyRequestHelper();
            if (traces != null) {
                helper.setTraces(traces);
            }
            return new AuthenticationHeaderFilter(helper, properties);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this isn't equivalent to the original auto-configuration but it works in our particular environment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Spring Cloud "**Angel**" together with Spring Boot "1.3". Instead you should use Spring Cloud "**Brixton**". Try to add a new parent like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and delete you version entries related to **org.springframework.cloud**.

You also need to add these repositories to be able to find the Brixton version:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And there is also a known bug in Spring Boot 1.3 you might need to handle: https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/30/migrating-oauth2-apps-from-spring-boot-1-2-to-1-3

Usefull examples:

- `https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/proxy/ui/pom.xml`
- `https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso/blob/master/pom.xml`

Comment: Hi @KLHauser, unfortunately I cannot use milestone releases in my environment and I have to stick with the GA releases. I have a temporary workaround that I'll add to the question. Thanks!